# не получается авторизовываться в битриксе через curl

Tags: php, curl, битрикс

с помощью curl пытаюсь авторизоваться в битриксе:

```
$paramspost = 'AUTH_FORM=Y&TYPE=AUTH&backurl=/oauth/authorize/?user_lang=ru&client_id=b24.5476e4faa69589.60034158&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Frosyurnadzor.bitrix24.ru%2Fauth%2F%3Fauth_service_id%3DBitrix24Net%26backurl%3D%252Fcrm%252Flead%252Flist%252F&scope=auth%2Cprofile&response_type=code&mode=page&state=site_id%3Ds1%26backurl%3D%252Fauth%252F%253Fcheck_key%253De3637b599be278e473006fbc01c8da85%2526backurl%253D%25252Fcrm%25252Flead%25252Flist%25252F%26mode%3Dpage&USER_LOGIN=логин&USER_PASSWORD=пароль&USER_REMEMBER=Y';








$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.bitrix24.net/auth/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $paramspost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Host: www.bitrix24.net',
'Connection: keep-alive',
'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Origin: https://www.bitrix24.net',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36',
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Referer: https://www.bitrix24.net/oauth/authorize/?user_lang=ru&client_id=b24.5476e4faa69589.60034158&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Frosyurnadzor.bitrix24.ru%2Fauth%2F%3Fauth_service_id%3DBitrix24Net%26backurl%3D%252Fcrm%252Flead%252Flist%252F&scope=auth%2Cprofile&response_type=code&mode=page&state=site_id%3Ds1%26backurl%3D%252Fauth%252F%253Fcheck_key%253De3637b599be278e473006fbc01c8da85%2526backurl%253D%25252Fcrm%25252Flead%25252Flist%25252F%26mode%3Dpage',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch',
'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
'Content-Length: '.strlen($paramspost)
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/bitrix.dat');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/bitrix.dat');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);  

$bx24result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $bx24result;
```

Выводит только заголовки, ни редиректа ничего не происходит, куки сохраняет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше используйте нормальные высокоуровневые библиотеки, а не чистый curl - в текущем вашем коде ничего не понятно.

Вот рабочий пример авторизации на этом сайте, использующий [guzzlehttp/guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle) для выполнения HTTP-запросов, и [querypath/querypath](https://packagist.org/packages/querypath/querypath) для выбора информации с HTML-страниц по CSS-селекторам:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

// Настройки клиента - можно вынести в какой-нибудь отдельный файл
$config = [
    'base_uri' => 'https://www.bitrix24.net/',
    'cookies' => true,
    'headers' => [
        'Accept-Language' => 'ru,en-US' // Если не задать - будут выдаватся страницы на английском языке
    ]
];

// Создаём экземпляр клиента - можно вынести в IoC-контейнер
$client = new Client($config);

// И.. Авторизуемся
$client->post('auth/', [
        'form_params' => [
            'AUTH_FORM' => 'Y',
            'TYPE' => 'AUTH',
            'backurl' => '/',
            'USER_LOGIN' => $login,
            'USER_PASSWORD' => $password,
            'USER_REMEMBER' => 'Y'
        ]
    ]
);

// Получаем QueryPath\DOMQuery из содержимого страницы profile.php
$profilePage = qp($client->get('profile.php')->getBody()->getContents());

// Выбираем текст элементов с классом 'user_name', и с id 'b24net_profile_link'
$profile = [
    'name' => qp($profilePage, '.user_name')->text(),
    'profile_link' => qp($profilePage, '#b24net_profile_link')->text()
];

// удаляем лишние пробелы, хоть можно и без этого
array_map('trim', $profile);

// ну и используем эти данные где-нибудь..
print_r($profile);
```